# Not able to access pear.drush.org

Tags: drush

So what happend to pear.drush.org I havent been able to access that page and drushs puppet module relies on it. Is the site down?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because DA is not forum about the status of website example.com is up or down.

Answer (score 2):

The Pear installation method for Drush was deprecated many years ago; I am not sure how long it has been unavailable, but it will not be coming back. The recommended and supported ways to download Drush are:

1. Use composer
2. Clone the git repository, then run `composer install`
3. Download the .phar

The [Drush Puppet module on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/puppet_drush) claims to support git and composer installation mechanisms; perhaps you'd have the best luck if you switched to using that one.

Comment: Personally, I recommend #2 if you are using Drupal 8 to make it easier to update frequently (should be less of an issue soon), and add the `composer install` as a post-merge hook in git.

Comment: Actually, for Drupal 8, the best thing to do is use a site-local Drush. See https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project and https://pantheon.io/blog/avoiding-dependency-hell-site-local-drush